# How do I tell if issues are caused by a faulty motherboard or Core i7 CPU memory controller?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, nehalem

My computer has an issue that results in random crashes. When I run memtest I get the same errors almost immediately (pictured).

They always occur at the same addresses even if I swap the sticks around, so I know the issue is with the PC not the memory. The errors only occur if slot 4 or above (of 6) is occupied on the motherboard.

At this point I would replace it, however the installed Core i7, having the Nehalem architecture, has the memory controller on board - so it could just as easily be this, no?

**Without replacing the CPU (I don't have a spare), is there any way to tell if this issue is on the motherboard or the CPU itself?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you're correct that the memory controller is now integrated into newer CPUs, it's very difficult to say which part is actually causing the failure (since it could also be some electrical issues on the motherboard itself).  Given the same consistent failure addresses, I would be inclined to lean towards it being an issue with the memory controller (and thus CPU die), but I've seen stranger things happen.

Your best bet would be to either test your motherboard with another CPU to see if the issue persists, or likewise, test your CPU in another motherboard to see if the issue is replicate-able.

Comment: Agree that the OP has only isolated the probable cause to be **not** the memory modules.  But I'm inclined to suspect the motherboard (with its sockets & multilayer traces) over the memory controller.

Comment: +1 As I agree this is the best thing to do in this situation, but unfortunately it is not possible. No-one I know has LGA1366 parts (they all have LGA1155) - not even my office IT dept. has spares - and since LGA1366 has been replaced by LGA2011 the components have gone up in price and become rarer, so even picking up cheap bits off eBay to test with is no longer an option.